# cannot clear the table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c

i have cleared the records on DB_REQUESTS table of DB_PROD schema, but after the tablespace free space is not increased. What to do?

```
delete from db_requests where to_char(to_date(transactiondate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
<='2021-05-31';

9566525 rows deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but `to_char(to_date(transactiondate,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') <='2021-05-31'` should be `transactiondate <= date '2021-05-31` to avoid unnecessary casts

Answer (score 1):

DELETE does not free up space for *other* tables, just for *this* table. If you want to get that space back then you could do:

```
alter table DB_REQUESTS move online
```

or

```
alter table DB_REQUESTS shrink space
```

But if this table is going to grow again, then you probably do not need either.

As an aside, what datatype is TRANSACTIONDATE? Because that to_date/to_char stuff generally is a bad idea unless absolutely necessary